# OpenBox pyPanel error with Imlib2 on OSX

Tags: macos, python, window-manager, openbox, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use pyPanel in OpenBox, but when I run it I get this error:

```
Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension
Imlib2 dlopen failed: dlopen(/usr/lib/libImlib2.so.1, 10): image not found
```

I have Imlib2 installed and in the correct dir, but I can't find libImlib2.so.1 anywhere.

I'm on OS X 10.8 ML

Answer (score 0):

You can tinker with setup.py to get around the issue. Edit setup.py in PyPanel to have right imlib2 shared library and imlib2 config directory i.e location of libImlib2.so.1 and imlib2-confg or you can create a symlinks in the /usr/bin where it expects them to be.